# CakePHP - Routing with parameters not working

Tags: cakephp, routes

I'm trying to connect this:

http://example.com/activate/A1B2C3

To this:

http://example.com/users/activate/A1B2C3

```
Router::connect('/activate/:token', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'activate'), array('pass' => 'token'));
```

But the parameter is not being passed along. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pass` must be an array.

```
Router::connect('/activate/:token', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'activate'),
    array('pass' => array('token'))
);
```